# how to access quantity dynamically and multiply with 100

Tags: python, dictionary

how to multiply all quantity dynamically using only one for loop

```
a = {'name': 'abc', 'lines': [
    (0, 0, {'product': 'abc', 'qty': 00}),
    (0, 0, {'product': 'gds', 'qty': 20}),
    (0, 0, {'product': 'def', 'qty': 100})]}
```

Comment: This is difficult because the values are within a tuple. However, `results = []; for v in a["lines"]: r = v[2]; r["qty"] *= 100; results.append(tuple(v[0], v[1], r))`. Finally, `a["lines"] = results`. Let me know if there are issues.

Comment: `for _, _, d in a['lines']: d['qty'] *= 100;`?

Comment: @LarrytheLlama `for v in a["lines"]: r = v[2]; r["qty"] *= 100;` would change the dicts in place. There's no need for `results` list.

Comment: @Ch3steR I thought tuples were unmodifiable? Maybe I am wrong...

Comment: @LarrytheLlama tuples sure are immutable but in that for you never changed `v` you accessed `v[2]` which gives you dict which can be modified in-place.

Comment: Thanks @Ch3steR , that makes complete sense.